# multiple textures on one mesh object.

Tags: materials

I am creating a fireplace in blender and I would like to assign a metal material and a glass material to different parts of the mesh. Could anyone explain how to do that? I have tried making two UV maps for the same object, but I actually don't know how to use these UV maps in the node editor. [image]

Comment: You can unwrap a selection of faces. Click the plus in UV Maps then in Edit mode select the faces that represent the glass and and unwrap those. Then in the Node editor Add an Input Node and set the UV name.

Comment: in Edit mode you have to select the part of the mesh and in the Properties panel > Material, you give it the material you want. Then in the Node Editor you create the material with the node organisation you need, Glass, Transparent, Glossy, etc... If you want to assign some Image Textures you need to unwrap this part of the mesh and create an Image Texture node in the Node Editor, that you'll plug into a Diffuse